# How would I use javascript to make an image "jiggle" or "shiver"?

Tags: javascript, html, image, vibration

So my question is simple, I'm building a webpage in HTML and I want to incorporate a little JavaScript into it so as to make an image "vibrate" or "jiggle" Basically move back and forth in a relatively tight space/pattern.

I did some research and I found this:

```
Copy the below code and paste it into the <HEAD> section of your page
Example:<head>Code Here</head>
<style>
.jc{
position:relative;
}
</style>

<script language="JavaScript1.2">

var ns6=document.getElementById&&!document.all
var ie=document.all

var customcollect=new Array()
var i=0

function jiggleit(num){
if ((!document.all&&!document.getElementById)) return;
customcollect[num].style.left=(parseInt(customcollect[num].style.left)==-1)? customcollect[num].style.left=1 : customcollect[num].style.left=-1
}

function init(){
if (ie){
while (eval("document.all.jiggle"+i)!=null){
customcollect[i]= eval("document.all.jiggle"+i)
i++
} 
}
else if (ns6){
while (document.getElementById("jiggle"+i)!=null){
customcollect[i]= document.getElementById("jiggle"+i)
i++
}
}

if (customcollect.length==1)
setInterval("jiggleit(0)",80)
else if (customcollect.length>1)
for (y=0;y<customcollect.length;y++){
var tempvariable='setInterval("jiggleit('+y+')",'+'100 )'
eval(tempvariable)
}
}

window.onload=init

</script>

NOW PASTE THIS ANYWHERE YOU WISH YOUR IMAGE TO APPEAR

<span id="jiggle0" class="jc"><b>YOUR IMAGE URL HERE</b></span>
```

They called it a "shivering pic" and gave an example... its exactly what I want. I did it exactly as they described it. I added the code where they said it was needed, I copied all the right parts (none of the directions), and I made sure everything is in the right place.

I tested it out an there was no image! There was nothing! I realized that this was because I was using a black background, and if there was any text, it would also be black, so what actually was happening was that it was merely showing the URL of the image I want to add in (I could see it once I highlighted it). Regardless, still no image (just the text), and still no vibrating/jittering/shivering/jiggling. I did note that there were bold tags right where it suggests to add the image URL... so to me that would make it seem like I would be putting in text.

PLEASE HELP! How do I make this code work, or how do I make an image "shiver"?

Comment: we need to see the HTML you actually used and not the instructions. Set up a fiddle on jsfiddle.net. Also, if you do a lot of animation related coding, you should consider one of many animation libraries out there. Would save you a lot of hassle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what you want :

[Dynamic Drive : Shake Image script](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/shake.htm)

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what is wrong with the above code, sorry.

I hate to toot my own horn, but I recently released a plugin that might work for you, if you are willing to use jQuery. It is called [jRumble](http://jackrugile.com/jrumble/). You can customize the X range, Y range, rotation range, rumble speed, and event type. It can be used on any element, so you could apply it directly to the image or to the div that the image is in, if you want.

Answer (score 1):

this line has an error :

```
customcollect[num].style.left=(parseInt(customcollect[num].style.left)==-1)? customcollect[num].style.left=1 : customcollect[num].style.left=-1
```

you probably want :

```
customcollect[num].style.left=(parseInt(customcollect[num].style.left)==-1) ? 1 : -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Mootools, Fx.Shake. Check [this](http://davidwalsh.name/mootools-shake) out!